# Using Vookup with a defined variable from an open window in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to insert a vlookup that has the rows as a defined variable taken from an open Excel Window.

The issue I'm facing right now is that the Vlookup is returning the amount of rows that are in the active workbook(namely "current.xlsm"). It is not taking the amount of rows from "dump-data.xlsm".

E.g. The total number of rows in "current.xlsm" is 8675. The total number of rows in "dump-data.xlsm" is 5934. While I want the Vlookup formula to return the total rows as 5934, it is returning 8675.

Please help! Thanks in advance

The code I have at the moment is:

```
Dim totalRows As Long

With Windows("dump-data.xlsm")
    totalRows = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = 
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[-12],[dump-data.xlsm]Data!R1C1:R" & totalRows & "C37,1,FALSE)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to refer to the correct worksheet

```
With Workbooks("dump-data.xlsm").Worksheets("Data")
    totalRows = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Unless you qualify which worksheet you are referring to, `Range` and `Rows` default to the `ActiveSheet`.  And a `With` block does not change which sheet is active, it simply provides a syntactical shortcut - i.e. you can type `.` instead of `Workbooks("dump-data.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").`.

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly! I will keep that in mind for next time.